# Error al ejecutar archivos ts con ts-node-dev

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, express

Estoy creando el backend de mi app con express y typescript, pero al ejecutar el paquete ts-node-dev me devuelve el siguiente error, Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

```
[INFO] 19:59:14 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.2, typescript ver. 5.3.3)
Compilation error in D:\Desarrollo\Crewmania\crewmania-back\src\index.ts
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: D:\Desarrollo\Crewmania\crewmania-back\src\index.ts
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Desarrollo\Crewmania\crewmania-back\src\index.ts:1:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._compile (D:\Desarrollo\Crewmania\crewmania-back\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-6975511709011217.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-6975511709011217.js:114:20)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (C:\Users\drake\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-6975511709011217.js:71:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (D:\Desarrollo\Crewmania\crewmania-back\node_modules\ts-node-dev\lib\hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
[ERROR] 19:59:15 Error: Must use import to load ES Module: D:\Desarrollo\Crewmania\crewmania-back\src\index.ts
```

Comment: Comparte el contenido del archivo `src\index.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Lo he logrado corregir.

Investigando, llegue a este [link](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev/issues/314) donde ofrecen una alternativa, pero no hacen uso de ts-node-dev, sino del propio nodemon.

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.